# Random generate password, isn't sending when created

Tags: user-roles, user, customer-account

I am running Magento 1.7 Community Edition. When I manually (admin panel) create a new user account for one of my clients and select randomly generate password it creates the user but never send the email with the password.

However if I revisit the user after its been created and recheck randomly generate password and click save it will send the email.

Any ideas why it won’t work when I create the user?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen and I narrowed it down to the fact that the email is not sent when associating the customer to the `Admin` website.
When doing this, the `website_id` for the customer is `0` and this code is executed in the controller:

```
if ($customer->getWebsiteId() && (isset($data['account']['sendemail']) || $sendPassToEmail)) {
    $storeId = $customer->getSendemailStoreId();
    if ($isNewCustomer) {
        $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('registered', '', $storeId);
    } elseif ((!$customer->getConfirmation())) {
        // Confirm not confirmed customer
        $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('confirmed', '', $storeId);
    }
}
```

`$customer->getWebsiteId()` is `0` so the `if` statement is skipped.
but when you edit the same customer again, the next piece of code is executed (right below the one I mentioned) and the e-mail is sent.

```
if (!empty($data['account']['new_password'])) {
    $newPassword = $data['account']['new_password'];
    if ($newPassword == 'auto') {
        $newPassword = $customer->generatePassword();
    }
    $customer->changePassword($newPassword);
    $customer->sendPasswordReminderEmail();
}
```